# When is a Vlan tag added into a frame?

Tags: linux, networking, vlan

I dont understand when does the vlan tag is first introduced in the frame.Is the NIC adapter driver or  switch that adds the vlan tag?
And who sets this 3-bit user Priority Code Point (PCP).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is the ethernet driver that adds a vlan tag into the ethernet frame.PCP value is also set by the ethernet driver.